# PHP-FPM status page is blank after nginx update from 1.2.1 to 1.9.2

Tags: php, nginx, status

I've been using Nginx 1.2.1 for a while now, and because of security issues, I decided to upgrade to 1.9.2.

**Problem is : php-fpm status page is now serving me a fully blank page.**
HTTP response code says : 200 ok, but content = 0 bytes

**What I tried :**

Checking Nginx user / group : it's www:www (as it was before)
Checking Php-FPM user / group : it's www:www (as it was before)
During aptitude upgrade, I chose to keep my config files

tail /var/log/nginx/error.log says : nothing
tail /var/log/nginx/mywebsite-error.log says : nothing
tail /var/log/php-fpm/php5-fpm.log says : nothing except some process trace finished but nothing relevant

I've been using this code before the upgrade, no problem :

```
    location ~ ^/(php_status|ping)$ {
    # access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow MY_IP_ADRESS;
    deny all;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Therefore, I tried using the syntax :

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

but that leads to a 502 from nginx and I don't think the issue is there.

I'm running out of options ...

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: You try restarting PHP-FPM?

Comment: many times, and nginx too

Comment: I would upgrade php5-fpm as well. Then read the following documentation on setting up configuration files with nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html This documentation goes through setting up the fastcgi proxy as well.

Comment: I did a full aptitude upgrade already

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/(php_status|ping)$ {
    # access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow MY_IP_ADRESS;
    deny all;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # This is important
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: `# This is important
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` is what I was missing, thank you!

Comment: old post, I forgot to come back here but that was indeed the following line that solved the issue : 
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Comment: @Sorcy Glad that this could help, and got accepted after almost 3 years :).

Comment: When adding `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` it 404s, vs before it's 200 but just empty

Comment: @SteveRobbins: Please open new questions with your configuration written down so others could help you.

Answer (score 15):

Seems it's enough to add only

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: You're right, this line only was enough, but credit goes to Tuanitim for it.

Thank you anyway.